# Set POJO for Gson when JSON key has a dash

Tags: java, android, json, gson

The JSON string is:

```
{
    "translation": ["some words"],
    "basic": {
        "us-phonetic": "'flæbɚɡæstɪd",
        "phonetic": "'flæbɚɡæstɪd",
        "uk-phonetic": "'flæbəga:stid",
        "explains": ["v. some words",
            "adj. some words"
        ]
    }
}
```

But Java can not have a value with a `"-"` in it. So how to get `"us-phonetic"`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a `POJO` class to represent your `JSON` and decorate your fields with the `SerializedName` annotation.

`gson` uses `@SerializedName("json_name")` when the name of the `JSON` field and the name of the java field are different.

I have taken the liberty to simplify your `JSON` for example purposes:

```
{
  "us-phonetic": "'flæbɚɡæstɪd",
  "phonetic": "'flæbɚɡæstɪd",
  "uk-phonetic": "'flæbəga:stid"
}
```

Use the following class to deserialize your JSON:

```
public class Basic {
  @SerializedName("us-phonetic")
  private String usPhonetic;

  @SerializedName("phonetic")
  private String phonetic;

  @SerializedName("uk-phonetic")
  private String ukPhonetic;
}
```

To deserialize:

```
Basic b = gson.fromJson(json, Basic.class);
```

Comment: But still not working.don't know why...just get a null

Comment: Very strange as I have just tested the above code and it works. Where do you get a `null` ?

Comment: OK,I know what's wrong.I naming usphonetic instead of usPhonetic